# TinyMCE Self-hosted with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, tinymce

i am trying to create a simple self-hosted TinyMCE with react. Currently my project is just show a simple textarea there is no toolbar or any style. I think a good way to integrate tinymce is by using a module loader. I read that react already includes webpack by using npx create-react-app.

```
Projectstructor
    root
    |-public
    |-skins
    |-src 
       |-App.js
       |-TinyEditorComponent.js
    |-webpack.config.js
```

What I have done step by step:

1. npx create-react-app my-app
2. $ npm install --save @tinymce/tinymce-react
3. cp -r node_modules/tinymce/skins skins
4. create file webpack.config.js

> ```
> const config = {
>   module: {
>     loaders: [
>       {
>         test: require.resolve("tinymce/tinymce"),
>         loaders: ["imports?this=>window", "exports?window.tinymce"],
>       },
>       {
>         test: /tinymce\/(themes|plugins)\//,
>         loaders: ["imports?this=>window"],
>       },
>     ],
>   },
> };
> ```

TextEditor Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// Import TinyMCE
import tinymce from "tinymce/tinymce";

// Default icons are required for TinyMCE 5.3 or above
import "tinymce/icons/default";

// A theme is also required
import "tinymce/themes/silver";

// Any plugins you want to use has to be imported
import "tinymce/plugins/paste";
import "tinymce/plugins/link";

class TinyEditorComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { editor: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: `#${this.props.id}`,
      skin_url: `./skins/content/dark`,
      plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount",
      ],
      toolbar: "undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor |",
      setup: editor => {
        this.setState({ editor });
        editor.on("keyup change", () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.props.onEditorChange(content);
        });
      },
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    tinymce.remove(this.state.editor);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <textarea
        id={this.props.id}
        value={this.props.content}
        onChange={e => console.log(e)}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default TinyEditorComponent;
```

I am not sure how to override and configure webpack for tinymce, there are alot of old ways but what is the right one. By injecting webconfig?

Comment: Does it work when you use a static ID for the text area?

Comment: could I ask why you're not using the official TinyMCE react component (`@tinymce/tinymce-react`)?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be using their own ReactComponent.
this answer takes knowledge from https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/

You should install the component `@tinymce/tinymce-react` via `npm` or `yarn` whichever is your preference. once you have installed that you import the editor

```js
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
```

You can then use it like so

```
<Editor
    initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
    init={{
      height: 500,
      menubar: false,
      plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
      ],
      toolbar:
        'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
         alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
         bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
      }}
/>
```

then add your self-hosted copy of TinyMCE to your public folder.
edit index.html inside the public folder and add the following inside your `<head>` tag

```html
<script src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following these steps:

In the webpack configuration, add:

```
const copyWebpack = new CopyWebpackPlugin({
  patterns: [
    { from: 'node_modules/tinymce', to: './static/tinymce/' }
  ]
});
```

Then, in your code, use the following:

```
<TinyMCEEditor
  tinymceScriptSrc="http://localhost:3000/static/tinymce/tinymce.js"
  apiKey="API_KEY"
  onEditorChange={(value) => onChange(value)}
  value={value}
  disabled={readonly}
  init={{
    skin: 'tinymce-5',
    content_css: false,
    inline: false,
    height: 400,
    width: '100%',
    plugins: ['link', 'lists', 'preview'],
    toolbar: true,
    toolbar_mode: mode
  }}
/>
```